# Why is this not creating a properties file?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a properties file in Java. Sadly, when I startup Minecraft (As this is a mod in Forge) the file is not created. I will be so thankful to anyone who helps me. Here is the code:

```
package mymod.properties;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class WriteToProperties {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.setProperty("Test", "Yay");

        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("Test.properties"), null);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Is it possible the file is being created in a directory you don't expect?  Try specifying a full path.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is `initialize(event.getSuggestedConfigurationFile());`

Forge basically wishes to hand you the default settings to you. I also suggest you structure things logically, so it's nice, clean and accessible later on, and easier to manage.

I use this as a config loader

```
package tschallacka.magiccookies.init;

import java.io.File;

import net.minecraftforge.common.config.Configuration;
import net.minecraftforge.common.config.Property;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import tschallacka.magiccookies.MagicCookies;
import tschallacka.magiccookies.api.ModHooks;
import tschallacka.magiccookies.api.Preferences;

public class ConfigLoader {
    public static Configuration config;
    public static final String CATEGORY_GENERAL = "GeneralSettings";
    public static final String CATEGORY_SERVER = "ServerPerformance";
    public static void init(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        ModHooks.MODID = MagicCookies.MODID;
        ModHooks.MODNAME = MagicCookies.MODNAME;
        ModHooks.VERSION = MagicCookies.VERSION;
        try {
            initialize(event.getSuggestedConfigurationFile());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            MagicCookies.log.error("MagicCookie failed to load preferences. Reverting to default");
        }
        finally {
            if (config != null) {
                save();
            }
        }
    }
    private static void initialize(final File file) {
        config = new Configuration(file);
        config.addCustomCategoryComment(CATEGORY_GENERAL, "General Settings");
        config.addCustomCategoryComment(CATEGORY_SERVER, "Server  performance settings");
        Preferences.magicCookieIsLoaded = true;
        config.load();
        syncConfigurable();
    }
    private static void save() {
        config.save();
    }
    private static void syncConfigurable() {

        final Property awesomeMod = config.get(Configuration.CATEGORY_GENERAL, "awesome_mod", Preferences.awesomeMod);
        awesomeMod.comment = "Set this to yes if you think this mod is awesome, maybe it will at some time unlock a special thing.... or not... but that's only for people who think this is an wesome Mod ;-)";
        Preferences.awesomeMod = awesomeMod.getString();

        final Property numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper = config.get(CATEGORY_SERVER,"number_of_blocks_placing_per_tick_by_stripper",Preferences.numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper);
        numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper.comment = "This affects how many blocks will be placed per tick by the creative stripper tool per tick. The stripper tool will only place blocks if ticks are take less than 50ms. If you experience lag lower this number, if you don't experience lag and want faster copy pasting, make this number higher. For an awesome slowmo build of your caste set this to 1 ;-). Set to 0 to render everything in one go per chunk";
        Preferences.numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper = numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper.getInt();

        final Property averageTickTimeCalculationSpan = config.get(CATEGORY_SERVER,"number_of_ticks_used_for_average_time_per_tick_calculation",Preferences.averageTickTimeCalculationSpan);
        averageTickTimeCalculationSpan.comment = "This number is the number of tick execution times are added together to calculation an average. The higher number means less lag by some things like the strippers, but can also lead to longer execution times for the strippers. Basically if your server is always running behind on server ticks set this value to 1, to at least get some work done when your server is running under 50ms tickspeed";
        Preferences.averageTickTimeCalculationSpan = averageTickTimeCalculationSpan.getInt();

        final Property acceptableTickduration = config.get(CATEGORY_SERVER,"acceptable_tick_duration",Preferences.acceptableTickduration);
        acceptableTickduration.comment = "Define here what you see as acceptable tick speed where MagicCookies can do some of its magic. If average tick speed or current tick speed is higher than this value it won't perform some tasks to help manage server load.";
        Preferences.acceptableTickduration = (long)acceptableTickduration.getDouble();
    }
}
```

The value holder Preferences class.
This is purely so I can do `Preferences.valuename` everywhere.

```
package tschallacka.magiccookies.api;
/**
 * Here the preferences of MagicCookies will be stored
 * and kept after the config's are loaded.
 * @author Tschallacka
 *
 */
public class Preferences {
    public static boolean magicCookieIsLoaded = false;
    public static String awesomeMod = "Well?";
    public static boolean isLoadedThaumcraft = false;
    public static int numberOfBlocksPlacingPerTickByStripper = 0;
    public static int averageTickTimeCalculationSpan = 60;
    public static long acceptableTickduration = 50l;
    public static int darkShrineFrequency = 0;
    public static boolean darkShrineSpawnLogging = true;
    public static boolean entropyTempleSpawnLogging = true;
    public static int entropySize = 30;
}
```

In your main mod file:

```
@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
    MagicCookies.log.warn("Preinit starting");
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register((Object)MagicCookies.instance);
    ConfigLoader.init(e);
}
```

And after that you can just fetch all your preferences from the Preferences class

Answer (score -1):

This file was created in root of your project. If you want some specific path to save, create folder in root of your project like *props* and change path in `FileOutputStream` constructor to `"props\\Test.properties"`

Comment: Alright. What exactly is the root of the project? Is there a way to check? (Or is it just the first file that contains everything?)

Comment: What IDE did you used to write this code? Eclipse, IDEA or only notepad?

Comment: @Betterjakers Right-click on root the folder in left panel and choose Propertise item of menu. There you will see Location element. That would be path to your project.

Comment: So if I want it to save in mymod, how would I do that? Picture: https://gyazo.com/f5f971595e798abf320845fef764b8f3

Comment: You can write absolute path like _C:\prop.properties_ or _C:\ProjectPath\src\mymood\prop.properties_ but this folders should be created before run application.

Comment: This is the code, but there is a red squiggly line under everything in quotes.                                                                                                                           prop.store(new FileOutputStream("C:\Minecraft\src\mymod\Test.properties"), null);

Comment: You'd write the path something like this C:\\Minecraft\\src\\mymod\\Test.properties

Comment: I see this error in the console on startup: java.io.FileNotFoundException: NameOfFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified).

Comment: I am very confused, please help.

Comment: @Betterjakers Find in your file system(by search) folder with name _mymod_ and write full pach to this folder in comment.